# In .NET Core, ASP.NET Core - What is the relationship between Package, Reference, NuGet Package, DLL file, Namespace

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

The IT industry loves to create buzzwords, some new, some are new twists on old things.  In .NET Core I read about Packages, References, NuGet Packages, DLL files and Namespaces.  I understand the simple basics/steps, but is there a consistent relationship between some/all of the above words?

1. Does a single Reference ALWAYS point to a single Package?
2. Is one Package ALWAYS made of one DLL?
3. Is NuGet Package same as a Package?
4. What is the relationship between DLL file and Packages?  1 to 1, 1 to many?  None?
5. Creating a Reference - is doing what?  Is it pointing to ONE Package or Many?
6. When I use "Using ABC.123.DEF;", am I creating a new Reference?  If not, would I already have created a Reference to that?  What does Creating a Reference do, includes the DLLs (other files) in my project, or just tells the compiler to do so at compile time?
7. Finally, what form does MetaPackage take in Core 3?  Is it a NuGet Package?

Comment: You'll find most of answers in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: Pavel, thank you!  I have been reading these docs for years; they do not clearly indicate the difference.  Do you have a link that clearly shows the difference/definitions?

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions here, but I'd like to recommend start reading at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget

Answer (score 1):

**DLL File**

A .dll (Dynamic Linked Library) file is a library that contains code and data that can be used by more than one program, each project that uses it adds a reference to it

**Nuget Packages**

Put simply, a NuGet package is a single ZIP file with the .nupkg extension that contains compiled code (DLLs), when you use Nuget pckage manager console to add packages. if i write a library that would be usefull to other developers, i can publish it to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org) as a nuget package

[Read more about nuget packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget)

**Package Reference**

A reference is essentially an entry in a project file that contains the information that Visual Studio needs to locate the component or the service.

for example, if you want to use EntityFramework in your project, you need to install it with the following command

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

This adds a package reference in the .csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
```

**Note**: versions may vary